Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined in React (Webpack), how to fix?
I’m working on a React project that uses JWT for authentication. Everything was working fine, but recently I encountered an error in the browser console saying:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined"
This error appears in the file readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js when I try to run the app.
Project Context:
React version: 18.3.1
Webpack version: 4.42.0 (updated to version 5 recently)
Key dependencies:

JWT: I’m using jsonwebtoken to generate and verify tokens.
React-router-dom: For routing.
Axios: For making HTTP requests.
React-bootstrap: For UI components.
Backend: I’m using Express and JWT for authentication

What I’ve Tried So Far:

Checking for usage of process: I identified that the error is
related to process usage inside readable-stream. I tried several
approaches to fix it:

Using polyfills for process and other Node.js modules (such as crypto, stream):
    config.resolve.fallback = {
  ...config.resolve.fallback,
  process: require.resolve('process/browser'),
  crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
  stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
};

But the error still persists, and process is not defined keeps appearing.

Reinstalling dependencies: I tried deleting node_modules and the
package-lock.json file, then running npm install. I also tried
updating several dependencies, including react-scripts and webpack.

Checking Webpack configuration: I checked my config-overrides.js
file to make sure it's correctly configured to use polyfills and
resolve Node.js dependencies. I followed the documentation for
customize-cra and webpack.

Using react-app-rewired: To avoid the limitations of
create-react-app, I’m using react-app-rewired to modify Webpack
configuration. I tried removing it and using react-scripts directly,
but no luck.

Updating Webpack: I updated Webpack from version 4.42.0 to 5.97.1, but
the error persists.


Relevant Files:

config-overrides.js:

const { override, addWebpackAlias } = require('customize-cra');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = override(
  addWebpackAlias({
    "http": require.resolve("stream-http"),
    "https": require.resolve("https-browserify"),
    "assert": require.resolve("assert/"),
    "util": require.resolve("util/"),
    "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib"),
    "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
    "url": require.resolve("url/"),
    "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
    "process": require.resolve("process/browser"), // Polyfill for process
  }),
  (config) => {
    config.resolve = {
      ...config.resolve,
      fallback: {
        ...config.resolve.fallback,
        process: require.resolve("process/browser"), // Ensuring 'process' is available
        crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
        stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
        buffer: require.resolve("buffer/"),
      },
    };
    config.plugins = [
      ...(config.plugins || []),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        process: 'process/browser',
        Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
      }),
    ];
    return config;
  }
);


package.json:

{
  "dependencies": {
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.0.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
    "axios": "^1.7.9",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.10.2"
  }
}

Console Error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at ./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:105779:18)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:141002:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:140424:32)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:140661:21)
    at ./node_modules/readable-stream/readable-browser.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:106604:20)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:141002:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:140424:32)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:140661:21)
    at ./node_modules/browserify-sign/browser/index.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28898:14)

Questions:

Why is process not defined even though I’ve correctly polyfilled it
in my Webpack config?
Is there another approach to fix the process
error with webpack?

Additional Details:

I have tried common solutions (adding polyfills and fallbacks), but I’m still encountering the same error.
I’m using jsonwebtoken for JWTand axios for API requests.
The error appears in the browser, not on the development server,
which makes me think there’s an issue in the Webpack client
configuration.


So this is create-react-app setup, isn't it? The question needs to contain this explicitly as this is a specific webpack config (and also deprecated). What you're trying could possibly work in WP in general, but it can be different with CRA
